# Specified cast is not Valid - bit value has NULL from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I use data from a stored procedure that returns two columns:  Paid and New

They both contain bit values. So, it returns 0 or 1, but some test data return a NULL.

```
Paid  New
 1     1
 0     0
 1    NULL
```

As a result I am getting this error

```
Specified cast is not valid
```

How would I resolve this issue in c# or better yet in the stored procedure itself, so that the stored procedure would only return 0 or 1.

Comment: Did you try isnull function in sql?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to read the results?

Comment: Thank you Doan... I will try that. I just have to figure how to use it... :)

Comment: also what is the Tables Data Definition, does it allow for `Null values` perhaps that should be setup to have a `default value set upon inserting a new record` this will save you the headache's of doing any `IsNull` checks most important when and where are you getting this error `Specified cast is not valid`

Comment: good point DJ... the thing is I didn't create these tables... it's a group project, but I will implement this when I am making my own table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Paid, ISNULL(New, 0)
```

This will return 0 instead of NULL in column "New". That is fix in stored procedure.

As for C# fix, you can cast nullable bit to nullable bool (bool?):

```
(bool?)sqlValue
```

Comment: Thank you Oleksandr... you are a genius